# How to tune kernel.pars of surv.svm in mlr3

Tags: mlr3

For survival SVM model, different kernel has different parameters, for example, the kernel "poly_kernel"(polynomial) has the `degree` parameter, but it is included in the `kernel.pars` argument. Then how can I tune the `degree`? Also, how can I tune `degree` and `kernel` together?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only find little information about the `kernel.pars` parameter in the documentation of `survivalsvm::survivalsvm()`. According to the documentation, `kernel.pars` should be a vector of length 1. The [code](https://github.com/imbs-hl/survivalsvm/blob/d0eec0d49f99de6cea8fe8fd8c9de6ba7c153bff/R/regression.R#L99C13-L99C24) of `survivalsvm` does not work if `kernel.pars` is longer than 1. However, if the kernel is set to `poly_kernel`, a second element is accessed [here](https://github.com/imbs-hl/survivalsvm/blob/d0eec0d49f99de6cea8fe8fd8c9de6ba7c153bff/R/kernels.R#L78). Probably the `degree` parameter. So I can't get `survivalsvm` to run with `poly_kernel`. Maybe you have to ask the maintainer. On the mlr3 side you have to use a transformation function to use such special parameters. [Here](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/chapters/chapter4/hyperparameter_optimization.html#sec-tune-trafo) you can find more information.

```r
library(mlr3tuning)
library(mlr3extralearners)
library(mlr3proba)

search_space = ps(
    kernel = p_fct(c("lin_kernel", "poly_kernel")),
    degree = p_int(lower = 2, upper = 5, depends = kernel == "poly_kernel"),
    gamma = p_dbl(lower = 1e-4, upper = 1e4, depends = kernel == "poly_kernel"),
    .extra_trafo = function(x, param_set) {
        if (x$kernel == "poly_kernel") {
        x$kernel.pars = c(x$gamma, x$degree)
        x$degree = NULL
        x$gamma = NULL
        }
        x
  }
)

# hyperparameter configs on the tuner side
design = paradox::generate_design_random(search_space, n = 10)
design

# hyperparameter configs on the learner side
design$transpose()

# tuning
instance = tune(
    tuner = tnr("random_search"),
    task = tsk("rats"),
    learner = lrn("surv.svm", gamma.mu = 1),
    resampling = rsmp("cv", folds = 3),
    terminator = trm("evals", n_evals = 20),
    search_space = search_space
)
```

Comment: Your answer is really helpful, thank you very much!